# How to deal with WebSocket on multiple servers?

Tags: ajax, websocket, real-time, autoscaling, spring-websocket

I have WebSocket implemented in a real-time application, where connected clients get all server updates without page refresh. That's fine and it's working very well.  The problem is as follows:

Lets say I use two servers (server1 and server2) to serve client requests. If a client on server1 updates the database, all clients connected to server1 will get the updates, as expected, because server1 is aware of all connected clients. However, clients connected to server2 do not get any updates because they are being served by server2 who is not aware of the database updates (the updates were done by a client on server1)!

Is there a standard way of handling this? Also assume I have many servers.

If this has been addressed before, I'd also appreciate a pointer to it.  Thanks

Comment: Anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Handling the DB values, changes should be the responsibility of each instance connected to the DB. Whereas sharing updates (requires DB change or not)across various clients should be the responsibility of the handler. For websocket usually such updates are handles by writing it to a pub/sub channel/queue such as reddis and all instances subscribed to appropriate channel. Whenever any instance wants all clients to receive an update it puts it on that queue and all the instances are able to receive and broadcast it